# <p:selectOneMenu editable = "true" > limit spcial char input

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Good day everyone,
im trying to find out if theres a way how to allow my selectOneMenu in primefaces, editable true, to accept only inputs of number and letters. im avoiding here the input of special characters. thanks for response in advance.

Comment: Should the check happen during typing, or during validating a submit?

Comment: hi @BalusC, this should happen during typing.